# Framework not found Metal for architecture armv7 archive error xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, archive, armv7

I am trying to submit my one app to iTunes,

I did all the required stuff in iTunes (description, screenshots, etc), and I guess I now have to archive and submit in xCode first, then wait for the binary to show up back in iTunes and click the "Submit for Review" once I've selected a binary.

Dilemma: in xCode, my app passed the validation, but  archive error

```
(null): Framework not found Metal for architecture armv7
(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Questions: What do I do a clean code and there are no problems. But when the archives shows this error -  xcode 5.1.1

archive :
[image]
error:
[image]

Many thanks,
ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through below link;

https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/66